# jQuery Colorbox Custom Pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, colorbox

I have a list of links that are inserted into a DIV element using jQuery and ajax. The list of links are paginated where I only show 10 links at a time. After the ajax call completes and the links are inserted into the DIV, I use the jQuery Colorbox plugin to open the link up in a nice Colorbox. Colorbox automatically groups the links that are on the page and generates pagination for them in the Colorbox.

However, since I am paginating the links when they are returned via ajax, Colorbox only sees 10 items at a time. When it generates the pagination it's not aware that there are more items that need to be included in the pagination. As a result, if I need to go past the first 10 items, I have to close the colorbox and go to the next page of links.

Can anyone help me with hooking into the method(s) in which Colorbox generates the pagination? I'd like to leverage the built in pagination functionality but not sure how I can achieve this without doing something outside of Colorbox completely.

Answer (score 0):

looks as if you would have to append new elements to the $related variable. looks also as if this variable is private, so you would have to add another function for adding images on the fly.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like I would have to modify the plugin. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to.